# Why won't this vuetify checkbox show as checked or unchecked based on a boolean value?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm not sure if this is a bug with vuetify, or maybe I am not understanding something basic about Vue. I am trying to set a vuetify checkbox's value using it's `:value` prop. I'm not using `v-model` because I don't need two-way binding. I just want it's checked state to be set based on a boolean within my component.

The boolean value is calculated in a computed, but when the value changes, the checkbox doesn't respond. Here's a codepen:

https://codepen.io/flyingl123/pen/PoPKYYX

I am expecting to see the checkbox checked on pageload, but it's not:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div>
      <v-row justify="space-around">
        <v-checkbox :value="boolValue" class="mx-2" label="Checkbox"></v-checkbox>
      </v-row>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({}),
  computed: {
    boolValue() {
      return true;
    }
  }
})
```

If I inspect the checkbox component in Vue dev tools, I see the value prop has the correct `true` setting, but the box isn't checked.

In my real application, when the `boolValue` changes, I do see the checkbox getting the correct prop value, but still the box does not become checked or unchecked. Why is this?

Answer (score 20):

Apparently the vuetify checkbox uses prop `input-value`, not `value`:

https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/11119#issuecomment-614420583

Answer (score 2):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61493558/4706651) by flyingL123 already states that the prop `input-value` works for `v-checkbox`.

I would like to add some information:

All Vuetify form input components have the prop `value` but two components don't use it for model binding (`v-checkbox` + `v-switch`). This leads to confusion, especially when the `value` prop still exists, also in the api documentation:

[`v-textfield`](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-text-field/) and nearly all other inputs:

> `value`               The input’s value

[`v-checkbox`](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-checkbox/)/[`v-switch`](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-switch/):

> `input-value`     The **v-model** bound value
> [...]
> `value`               The input’s value

It is very easy to miss `input-value` in the middle of other props. I think there might be a reason why these boolean inputs use `input-value`. It's a pity that this isn't really made clear in the docs.

Answer (score -1):

You need to Replace `:value` with `v-model`

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div>
      <v-row justify="space-around">
        <v-checkbox v-model="boolValue" class="mx-2" label="Checkbox"></v-checkbox>
      </v-row>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: >I'm not using v-model because I don't need two-way binding.

v-model is two way binding.